# personFields mask is required. Please specify one or more valid paths

Tags: android, google-api, kotlin, google-people-api

Hi Referred this [link](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/http-auth) to call people/me API and getting this error

```
    01-12 12:33:12.859 22112-22285/com.nuveda.gol W/System.err: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
01-12 12:33:12.859 22112-22285/com.nuveda.gol W/System.err: {
01-12 12:33:12.859 22112-22285/com.nuveda.gol W/System.err:   "code" : 400,
01-12 12:33:12.859 22112-22285/com.nuveda.gol W/System.err:   "errors" : [ {
01-12 12:33:12.859 22112-22285/com.nuveda.gol W/System.err:     "domain" : "global",
01-12 12:33:12.860 22112-22285/com.nuveda.gol W/System.err:     "message" : "personFields mask is required. Please specify one or more valid paths. Valid paths are documented at https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get.",
01-12 12:33:12.860 22112-22285/com.nuveda.gol W/System.err:     "reason" : "badRequest"
01-12 12:33:12.860 22112-22285/com.nuveda.gol W/System.err:   } ],
01-12 12:33:12.860 22112-22285/com.nuveda.gol W/System.err:   "message" : "personFields mask is required. Please specify one or more valid paths. Valid paths are documented at https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get.",
01-12 12:33:12.860 22112-22285/com.nuveda.gol W/System.err:   "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
01-12 12:33:12.860 22112-22285/com.nuveda.gol W/System.err: }
```

I unable to set personField. Anybody can tell how to set personFields with refer to that document.

Here is my code :

```
 val SCOPE_USER_INFO = Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile")
        val SCOPE_USER_INFO = Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly")
        val SCOPE_EMAIL = Scope(Scopes.EMAIL)

        // Configure Google Sign In
        val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(context.getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestProfile()
                .requestScopes(SCOPE_USER_INFO, SCOPE_EMAIL)
                .requestEmail()
                .build()

        // [END config_signin]

        mGoogleApiClient = GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                .enableAutoManage(context as AppCompatActivity /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build()


private fun signIn() {
        val signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient)
        (context as AppCompatActivity).startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN)
    }

private fun updateUI(user: FirebaseUser?) {
        if (user != null) {
            val account : GoogleSignInAccount? = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(context)
            if (account != null) {
                val googleProfileAsync  = GoogleProfileAsync(context = activity, account = account.account!!)
                googleProfileAsync.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)
            }
        } else {
            signIn()
        }
    }

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN && data != null) {

            val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
            try {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                val account = task.getResult<ApiException>(ApiException::class.java)
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account)
            } catch (e: ApiException) {
                GOLLog.d("Google sign in failed" + e)
            }


        }
    }

private fun firebaseAuthWithGoogle(acct: GoogleSignInAccount) {
        GOLLog.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.id!!)
        showProgressDialog()
        val credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.idToken, null)
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(context as AppCompatActivity) { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        val user = mAuth.currentUser
                        updateUI(user)
                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        updateUI(null)
                    }

                    // ...
                }
    }

    private class GoogleProfileAsync internal constructor(context: LoginActivity, private val account: Account) : AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Person>?>() {
            private val context: WeakReference<LoginActivity> = WeakReference(context)
            /** Global instance of the HTTP transport.  */
            private val HTTP_TRANSPORT = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport()
            /** Global instance of the JSON factory.  */
            private val JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance()
            private val mProgressDialog: ProgressDialog =ProgressDialog(context)


            override fun onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute()
                GOLLog.d("On PReExecute")
                    mProgressDialog.setMessage(context.get()?.getString(R.string.loading))
                    mProgressDialog.isIndeterminate = true
                    mProgressDialog.show()
            }

            override fun doInBackground(vararg voids: Void): List<Person>? {
                GOLLog.d("doInBackground")
                var response: List<Person>? = null
                try {


                    val scopes: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly"/*, "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"*/)
                    val credential: GoogleAccountCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                            context.get(),
                            scopes
                    )
                    credential.selectedAccount = account

                    val service: People = People.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                   .setApplicationName("REST API sample")
                   .build()


                    val connectionsResponse: ListConnectionsResponse = service
                   .people()
                   .connections()
                   .list("people/me")
                   .execute()
                    response = connectionsResponse.connections

                } catch (e: UserRecoverableAuthIOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                    GOLLog.d("Authentication Failed")
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }

                return response
            }

            override fun onPostExecute(response: List<Person>?) {
                super.onPostExecute(response)
                GOLLog.d("onPostExecute")
                mProgressDialog.hide()
                if (response != null) {
                    GOLLog.d("Response "  + response)
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: I tried `list("people/me?personFields=names")` but it giving `error message : Invalid personFields mask path: \"names/connections\".`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that you need to [set personFields](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/people/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/people/v1/PeopleService.People.GetBatchGet.html#setRequestMaskIncludeField(java.lang.String)) mask.

From [google samples](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/signin/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/quickstart/signin/RestApiActivity.java)

```
PeopleService service = new PeopleService.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
.setApplicationName("Google Sign In Quickstart")
.build();

ListConnectionsResponse connectionsResponse = service
.people()
.connections()
.list("people/me")
.setPersonFields("names,emailAddresses")
.execute();
```

Comment: Yeah but, `requestMask` parameter is deprecated now. this document says explicitly to set personFields. https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get

But from your reference  link only having setPersonFields function but we can't access it why? https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/people/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/people/v1/PeopleService.People.GetBatchGet.html#setPersonFields(java.lang.String)

Comment: Exactly my issue is unable to call `setPersonFields("names,emailAddresses")`. But `setRequestMaskIncludeField` is working

Comment: What version of google api service do you use? https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/signin/app/build.gradle

Comment: Yes previously I used `compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-people:v1-rev4-1.22.0'` and updated to latest `compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-people:v1-rev139-1.22.0'` It is working. 
But in google docs they didn't updated this

Comment: How to use for the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login` now I am getting for the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly`

Answer (score 4):

This also works...

```
    ListConnectionsResponse connectionsResponse = service
                    .people()
                    .connections()
                    .list("people/me")
                    .set("personFields","names,addresses,birthdays,genders,phoneNumbers,photos")
                    .execute();
```